# How do I create property arrays in NEO4 Cypher?

Tags: arrays, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create and entity which has a property that contains an array/list of items. I can't understand how I can do:

1. create the property array
2. perform an append to the array
3. parse the array property

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

This helps solve a many to 1 relationship issue I am facing.

Answer (score 7):

```
// Create a node with an array prop
CREATE (n:Test { my_array:['a', 'b', 'c']}) RETURN n;
+-------------------------------------+
| n                                   |
+-------------------------------------+
| (:Test {my_array: ["a", "b", "c"]}) |
+-------------------------------------+

// append the value 'd' in the array
MATCH (n:Test) SET n.my_array=n.my_array+ 'd' RETURN n;
+------------------------------------------+
| n                                        |
+------------------------------------------+
| (:Test {my_array: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]}) |
+------------------------------------------+


// Remove the value 'b' from the array
MATCH (n:Test) SET n.my_array=filter(x IN n.my_array WHERE x <> 'b')  RETURN n;
+-------------------------------------+
| n                                   |
+-------------------------------------+
| (:Test {my_array: ["a", "c", "d"]}) |
+-------------------------------------+


// Don't forget the magic UNWIND  with arrays
MATCH (n:Test) UNWIND n.my_array AS item  RETURN item;
+------+
| item |
+------+
| "a"  |
| "c"  |
| "d"  |
+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Remove the value 'b' from the array
// modified the existing answer by replacing filter with a list comprehension 
// which creates a new list containing only the elements that are not equal to 'b'. 

    MATCH (n:Test)
    SET n.my_array = [x IN n.my_array WHERE x <> 'b']
    RETURN n;

+-------------------------------------+
| n                                   |
+-------------------------------------+
| (:Test {my_array: ["a", "c", "d"]}) |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).